# Compile C like different versions of gcc

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, debian

i hope you can help me.
i need to compile my sourcecode like gcc 3.3.6 does
Is this possible with gcc 7.3.0?

do you have solutions?

are there other programms to compile like specific versions?

Comment: Can you tell us *why*?

Comment: i want to disassemble different versions to see differences

Comment: @DavideSpataro Godbolt goes back only to GCC 4.1.2

Comment: A newer version of GCC cannot emulate an older version. You should probably
explain the real problem you are ultimately trying to solve.

Comment: i have a old book with some dissassemled assembler code.
the book is build on 3.3.6. I compile with 7 thats a huge difference

Comment: How about installing this version on your machine? If you afraid to mess up your environment, use a virtual machine.

Comment: i hoped there is a better solution :)

Comment: Well, I can also suggest to get a newer book :) That one is probably outdated in some other stuff as well.

Comment: yeah sure, but enough for the basics :)